# Java Multi Threading Invoke Other only when first is done

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

Runnable firstWorker = new DataComparison(DataComparison.FIRST_THREAD_INSTANCE,args[0], args[1], args[2], runSkey, fic_mis_date,legal_entity, args[6],failover);
executor.execute(firstWorker);

Runnable secondWorker = new DataComparison(DataComparison.SECOND_THREAD_INSTANCE,args[0], args[1], args[2], runSkey, fic_mis_date,legal_entity, args[6],failover);
executor.execute(secondWorker);

Runnable thirdWorker = new DataComparison(DataComparison.THIRD_THREAD_INSTANCE,args[0], args[1], args[2], runSkey, fic_mis_date,legal_entity, args[6],failover);
executor.execute(thirdWorker);
```

this is my code wherein i want to invoke second and third thread only when first has completed processing. I am confused between `AwaitTermination` and `sleep`. Kindly suggest.

Comment: I am confused why your title talks about multithreading and your question is about running things sequentially.

Comment: Title is very clear but not your question :)

Comment: there is a **much** simpler solution : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 CompletableFuture you can write

```
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
 Runnable firstWorker = new DataComparison(DataComparison.FIRST_THREAD_INSTANCE,args[0], args[1], args[2], runSkey, fic_mis_date,legal_entity, args[6],failover);


 Runnable secondWorker = new DataComparison(DataComparison.SECOND_THREAD_INSTANCE,args[0], args[1], args[2], runSkey, fic_mis_date,legal_entity, args[6],failover);


  Runnable thirdWorker = new DataComparison(DataComparison.THIRD_THREAD_INSTANCE,args[0], args[1], args[2], runSkey, fic_mis_date,legal_entity, args[6],failover);

 CompletableFuture firstTask = CompletableFuture.runAsync(firstWorker,
          executor);
 firstTask.thenRunAsync(secondWorker,executor)
 firstTask.thenRunAsync(thirdWorker,executor);
```

This will start the second and third tasks when the first completes.

Comment: I was thinking about using a CountDownLatch but I think your answer is the best

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, using Guava's support for futures might be really helpful. 
I would refer to this [article by google](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) to learn a little bit more about `ListenableFuture`. Here is a code sample based on your code, though if you do plan to use Guava's Futures, I would probably build my code a bit differently:

```
    ListeningExecutorService s = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
    Runnable firstWorker = new DataComparison(1);

    final Runnable secondWorker = new DataComparison(2);

    final Runnable thirdWorker = new DataComparison(3);

    ListenableFuture f = s.submit(firstWorker);

    Futures.addCallback(f, new FutureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
            secondWorker.run();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        }
    });

    Futures.addCallback(f, new FutureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
            thirdWorker.run();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        }
    });
```

What happens here is that first we submit the first worker, and then add 2 callbacks to it (`secondWorker` and `thirdWorker`). The `onSuccess` method will be called once `firstWorker` completes successfully. If it throws an exception, `onFailure` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple possibility.  There are other more complicated things that you could do, but if I understand your question correctly, this should do what you want:

```
final Runnable firstWorker = new DataComparison(DataComparison.FIRST_THREAD_INSTANCE,args[0], args[1], args[2], runSkey, fic_mis_date,legal_entity, args[6],failover);
final Runnable secondWorker = new DataComparison(DataComparison.SECOND_THREAD_INSTANCE,args[0], args[1], args[2], runSkey, fic_mis_date,legal_entity, args[6],failover);
final Runnable thirdWorker = new DataComparison(DataComparison.THIRD_THREAD_INSTANCE,args[0], args[1], args[2], runSkey, fic_mis_date,legal_entity, args[6],failover);

Runnable combined = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    firstWorker.run();
    executor.execute(secondWorker);
    executor.execute(thirdWorker);
  }
};

executor.execute(combined);
```